# Bootstrap Datetimepicker wrong default date with minDate

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, momentjs, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I'm using Eonasdan Bootstrap Datetimepicker: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Although I can't get the minDate and maxDate to work as expected. Since the date is dynamic and changes the fiddle is set upp with moments.js´ subtract/add

**Conditions**

```
minDate = today + 1 day
maxDate = today + 3 days
default value = today + 2 days
```

The above returns the value tomorrow and not the default value. If minDate is changed to -2 days it works just fine.

See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9uqpu88v/8/

```
twoDaysFromToday =  moment().add(2, 'd').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

$('#datetimepicker1 input').val(twoDaysFromToday); 
      var datetimepicker = $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
      minDate: moment().add(1, 'd').format('YYYY-MM-DD'), // Tomorrow
      maxDate: moment().add(3, 'd').format('YYYY-MM-DD'), // Three days from today
    })


<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
    <input type="text" id="datetimepicker1" class="form-control" value="" />    
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is `moment()` doing?

Comment: I see no issue in your fiddle (`minDate` and `maxDate` are set to the given "hardcoded" value), while your snippet is missing required libraries. Anyway I suggest to use moment parsing function specifying format (see [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)). In your example: `moment('2016-07-01, 'YYYY-MM-DD')` instead of `moment('2016-07-01')`.

Comment: I've edited the Fiddle

Answer (score 2):

You can pass moment object instead of string to `minDate` and `maxDate`. Use [`defaultDate`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#defaultdate) option to set the value to your picker instead of jQuery `val()`. Note that the library provides also a [`date`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#date) method to set value to the component.

Use moment [`startOf`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) to be hour independent.

Here a working example:

```js
var datetimepicker1 = $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
  useCurrent: false,
  defaultDate: moment().startOf('day').add(2, 'd'),
  minDate: moment().startOf('day').add(1, 'd'),
  maxDate: moment().startOf('day').add(3, 'd')
})
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```